# How to determine whether to use "which" or "what"?

Tags: word-choice, that-vs-which

I understand that we use *which* when options are limited and *what* when there is no limitation. Check this sentence:

> 1. Tell me about things **what** make you angry.

Is this sentence ok, or is *which* necessary? Or one more example:

> 2. These are things **which** you wanted.

I can hear that using *what* is wrong, but why?

Comment: Just because *which* and *what* work as a pair in one situation, does not make them substitutes everywhere. Both examples call for the word **that** here.

Comment: The contrast between "what" and selective "which" apples to interrogative clauses, not relative clauses like the ones in your examples. 1. is ungrammatical because "what" is not a relative pronoun: "that" or "which" is required. 2. is OK.

Answer (score 2):

#1 is incorrect.

Both examples have a **defining** relative clause.

As the relative clauses describe **things**, we use the relative pronoun **which**, or the relativiser **that** in the two cases here as these are **defining** relative clauses.

In #2, the **which**/**that** can be omitted as it is the **object** of the relative clause.

I rewrite the two sentences, with the words in parentheses being optional.

> Tell me about things **which/that** make you angry.

> These are [the] things (**which/that**) you wanted.

**What** is not a relative pronoun and cannot be used in this manner.